# sharepoint 2013 Form background colour infopath

Tags: infopath, style.css

Trying to change the background colour from white to transparent, infopath is adding 'inline styles'. I ultimately want this to be transparent and the form border, text etc to be white to display over the fullsize background image.

[image]

Code Sample:

```
padding:25px;background-color:window;color:windowtext;color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:window;color:windowtext;color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:window;color:windowtext;color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:window;color:windowtext;color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:window;color:windowtext;color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size:10pt;DIRECTION: ltr; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; padding-top:16px;padding-bottom:16px;margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;zoom:100%"
```

I have tried the following:
+ Add a new CSS reference to the ID (in screenshot)
+ Tried to use a javascript inline stripper

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not proud of this, but it should work if you execute this after the form renders.

```
$("#WebPartWPQ1 *").css("background-color", "transparent")
```

Comment: This works. I have added it to a .js which loads via the footer - Thanks @James

Comment: I implemented this and it works perfectly